# Hamming distance of linear block code(7,2)

Tags: coding-theory

How would I go about calculating the hamming distance of linear block code(7,2)?

I'm given nothing else, I know that the code will be 7 bits long, have 2 data bits and 5 error bits.

Comment: You cannot compute the distance with only the parameters $(n,k)$, you need the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** *This answer describes the limits on the possible minimum distance values. Too long for a comment.*

Since the code has $2^2=4$ codewords and there are $2^7=128$ vectors in the space, the maximum possible volume $V$ of disjoint equal radius hamming spheres must
obey
$$
V\leq 32.
$$
Since
$$
1+ \binom{7}{1}+ \binom{7}{2}=29<32
$$
it is conceivable that a 2 error correcting code with minimum Hamming distance 5 exists.

The optimal $(7,4)$ Hamming code has distance $3.$ You can't, however select a subset of its codewords and obtain a code with minimum distance 5, since its weight distribution (hence distance distribution, being linear) is not supported at 5. It has no weight 5 codewords.

Comment: If you have two words of weight $\ge5$ and length $7$ in how at least how many positions will the $1$s of the two words overlap? What does this tell you about the weight of their sum? Also, look up [Griesmer bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griesmer_bound).

Comment: Anyway, you are right about the weight distribution of the $(7,4)$ Hamming code.